# how to get the order of message in a mail conversation using " ConversationIndex " attribute?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, message

I am currently working with the mail data in GraphAPI. I need to get the order of messages in a mail conversation. I have the **Conversation Index** of messages in the conversation.

How to get the position/order of messages using the **Conversation Index ?**

User 1 message converstionIndex : AQHXa/g7jienD/k6UUuD7h/+vh/4PQ==

User 2 message converstionIndex : AQHXa/g7jienD/k6UUuD7h/+vh/4PaspGJ7v

User 1 message converstionIndex : AQHXa/g7jienD/k6UUuD7h/+vh/4PaspGJ7vgAAARsM=

User 2 message converstionIndex : AQHXa/g7jienD/k6UUuD7h/+vh/4PaspGJ7vgAAARsOAAAA9xA==

User 1 message converstionIndex : AQHXa/g7jienD/k6UUuD7h/+vh/4PaspGJ7vgAAARsOAAAA9xIAAACfU

User 2 message converstionIndex : AQHXa/g7jienD/k6UUuD7h/+vh/4PaspGJ7vgAAARsOAAAA9xIAAACfUgAAAOmw=
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain how this works in Outlook as the corresponding tag was added to the question.

The `ConversationIndex` property is a string that represents a hexadecimal number. Valid characters within the string include the numbers 0 through 9 and the letters A through F (uppercase or lowercase).

A conversation is a group of related messages that have the same `ConversationTopic` property value. In a discussion application, for example, users can save original messages and responses in their personal folders. Messages can be tagged with the `ConversationIndex` property so that users can order the messages within the conversation.

This convention uses concatenated time stamp values, with each new message in the conversation adding a new time stamp to the end of the `ConversationIndex` string. You can see time relationships among the messages when you sort them by `ConversationIndex` values.

For more information on conversations, see [Working With Conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms528195(v=exchg.10)).

Note, the [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms527464(v=exchg.10)) object provides the [CreateConversationIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms527456(v=exchg.10)) method to create or update a conversation index.

Answer (score 1):

this is how:

```
  private static getIsFirstMessageInConversation(conversationIndex?: string): boolean {
    if (!conversationIndex) return false;
        const FIRST_MESSAGE_IN_CONVERSATION_BYTES_LENGTH = 22;
        return atob(conversationIndex).length === FIRST_MESSAGE_IN_CONVERSATION_BYTES_LENGTH;
  }
```